# Flex 3: How do I set a gradient background color of a *selected* Tabbar tab instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Is there a way of setting the **selected** tab of a TabBar so that it contains a gradient background color?  I would have thought that combining `fillColors` and `fillAplhas` would be the styles to use but this sets the other **non selected** tab background colors as you can see if you run the code below.

The goal is to get end users to choose the background color of the selected tab instance (by using a ColorPicker for example).  And I want to apply some gradient effect on this color.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying to get this working for far too long.  I have searched endlessly on google for this but still can't get a working solution.

```
private function updateTabColor():void {        
    var selectedTabIndex : int = tabBar.selectedIndex;        
    var tab:Tab = Tab(tabBar.getChildAt(selectedTabIndex));

    /* this works but not on the selected tab */
    tab.setStyle("fillColors", ["#000000", "000000"]);
    tab.setStyle("fillAlphas", [1.0, 0.4]);

    /* when not commented and as expected, tab is red */ 
    //tab.setStyle("backgroundColor", "red");

    /* when not commented, doesn't work as it appears it's deprecated in 3.0 */
    //tab.setStyle("selectedFillColors", "red");   
}

<mx:TabBar id="tabBar" dataProvider="viewStack" width="100%" itemClick="{updateTabColor()}"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack"  width="100%" height="100%">
  <mx:Box id="tab1" label="tab1" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <mx:Box id="tab2" label="tab2" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <mx:Box id="tab3" label="tab3" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: I suggest using this online tool as a simple reference, sometimes this is easier than digging through the docs to get what you want: http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#app=a712&19f4-selectedIndex=23&1b1e-selectedIndex=0&b108-selectedIndex=0 if that doesn't work out, I suggest using Ctrl+Shift+T or Ctrl clicking TabBar to open the source it's all in your sdks folder if it complains that it can't be found let me know.  The easiest way to do whatever you want in Flex is to look through the source your depending on.

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain - I did do exactly as you said yesterday but that didn't really help.  The example only has a TabNavigator which is kinda similar but nothing about TabBar.  No style example for the *selected* tab instance.  Surely this is a standard requirement right?

Comment: No problem, but from what I know a TabNavigator is just a ViewStack that has a TabBar already combined for you so it shouldn't vary too much, was just assuming if you can get what you want in there it'll help you find the style name on the TabBar, I'll try to check it out here for a few minutes and see if I can figure out what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Okay just glanced it over then did a bit of googling think I have a link to a good answer

Answer (score 0):

http://userflex.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/skin-tabnavigator-tabs/

^ describes using a skin for the tab instead of using the styles provided

Copied here for history

CSS

```
.tab
{
     up-skin: ClassReference("TabSkin");
     down-skin: ClassReference("TabSkin");
     over-skin: ClassReference("TabSkin");
     selected-up-skin: ClassReference("SelectedTabSkin");
     selected-down-skin: ClassReference("SelectedTabSkin");
     selected-over-skin: ClassReference("SelectedTabSkin");

     background-color: #FFFFFF;

     font-weight: normal;
     color: #000000;
     text-roll-over-color: #000000;

     corner-radius: 0;

     border-style: solid;
     border-thickness: 1;
     border-color: #000000;
}

.selectedTab
{
     background-color: #000000;

     font-weight: bold;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     text-roll-over-color: #FFFFFF;

     corner-radius: 0;

     border-style: solid;
     border-thickness: 1;
     border-color: #000000;
}
```

AS3

```
package
{
     import mx.containers.Canvas;

     public class TabSkin extends Canvas
     {
         override protected function updateDisplayList
             (w : Number, h : Number) : void
         {
             this.styleName = "tab";

             super.updateDisplayList (w, h);
         }
     }
}

package
{
     import mx.containers.Canvas;

     public class SelectedTabSkin extends Canvas
     {
         override protected function updateDisplayList
             (w : Number, h : Number) : void
         {
             this.styleName = "selectedTab";

             super.updateDisplayList (w, h);
         }

     }
}
```

MXML

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabs"
    tabStyleName="tab" selectedTabTextStyleName="selectedTab" />
```

Comment: Thanks again @shaunhusain for this so far.  I'm unable to check it for a couple of days.  Two points I'd like to mention as highlighted in the original question:

1. I'm assuming it's possible to include a fillColor and fillAlphas in the styles.  (I've lost confidence using these two styles as it doesn't appear to work as expected for *selected* tabs).  I'm aiming for a gradient effect.

2. The color must be updatable dynamically (user can use ColorPicker to choose the color).  Then use AS3 to dynamically update the style with the selected color (I guess using 'fillColor' and 'fillAlphas').

Comment: @NormRozental you should be able to make a custom skin then handle the drawing in there, if the existing tab bar doesn't have the styling metadata in it to accept particular values for the selected button you may need to extend TabBar to add these styles and use your skin to act on the new custom styles you make (Flex doesn't always give you everything you want out of the box some of this is improved in the decoupling of the components from their skins and layouts in Flex 4 so it's a bit more convoluted to do with Flex 3 but this should be achievable if I have time I'll get it closer.